# Pytest says 'ModuleNotFoundError' when using tox

Tags: python, pytest, tox

I have the following project structure:

```
root
|- module
  |- module.py
  |- __init__.py
|- tests
   |- unit
      |- some_test.py
   |- integration
      |- another_test.py
|- conftest.py
|- setup.py
|- tox.ini
```

When I run `python3 module/module.py ...` it runs as expected.

However, when I execute `tox`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dateutil'`.

In my setup.py I have `install_requires=['python-dateutil']` and tox.ini has the following (simplified) contents:

```
[tox]
envlist   = py{36, 37}
skipsdist = True

[testenv]
deps = pytest
commands = pytest
```

Does anyone have any insight as to why running `tox` gives me that the module 'dateutil' cannot be found and how to fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`[tox]skipsdist = True` [prevents](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html#conf-skipsdist) `tox` to run `python setup.py sdist` so your `install_requires` is completely ignored.

If you really want to follow the advice to set `[tox]skipsdist = True` for applications you are also advised to follow all other best practices for packaging applications: use `requirements.txt` and add

```
[testenv]
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt
```

to `tox.ini`. Or just directly

```
[testenv]
deps = python-dateutil
```

Answer (score 6):

What helped me:

1. Add missing modules to the `install_requires` section of the `setup.py`
2. Delete old `.tox` directory and re-run `tox`

Comment: I'm using flit, but deleting the `.tox` directory and re-running `tox` solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: exactly, there is even a simple command     `python -m tox --recreate`

Answer (score 2):

If none of the answers dated before my post works, try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74938522/7751438) from [Jürgen Gmach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/672833/j%C3%BCrgen-gmach), which states the below:

> tox version 4 has been released a couple of weeks ago.
>
> There were a couple of breaking changes, see
> https://tox.wiki/en/latest/faq.html#breaking-changes-in-tox-4
>
> I would recommend to create an issue at
> https://github.com/tox-dev/tox/issues
>
> In the meantime, to get your CI unblocked, I would recommend to pin
> tox < 4 in your github actions.